# How to make my delete component being invoked?

Tags: reactjs, api, web-frontend

I'm trying to implement a full stack task app. My endpoint is working perfectly because i checked it with POSTMAN. However, when I try to run the delete request on my frontend react app, it fails to even invoke the `deleteTask` that I invoked in `handleClick`. I currently have two files, in the first file it generates a list of tasks with the task information like its `id`,`name` if it is completed. When the user clicks on the delete icon my other component in another file would be invoked. In the main file, i'm passing the id as props. Could someone help me to figure out why my `DeleteTask` is not invoking. Also i Know its not invoking because nothing is being displayed to console, no errors nothing at all and in my frontend and backend, i have error messages for each possible output.
the main file

```
import {useState , useEffect} from 'react'
import DeleteTask from './deleteTask'


const GetTask = () => {
    const [tasks , setTasks] = useState([])

    useEffect( () =>{
        (async () => {
            try {

                await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/v1/tasks/', {
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers : {
                        'Content-type' : 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
                    }
                })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    setTasks(data)
                    console.log(data)

                })
            }
            catch(error){
                console.log(error)
            }
        })()

    }, [])

    const handleDelete = (taskID) => {

        <DeleteTask id = {taskID}/>
     

    }
    return(

        <div>
        {

            tasks.map(task =>

            <div>
                { task.isCompleted ? (

                <div className="alert alert-primary d-flex align-items-center" role="alert">
                    <svg className="bi flex-shrink-0 me-2" width="24" height="24" role="img" aria-label="Danger:"><use xlink:href="#exclamation-triangle-fill"/>
                    <path d="M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0zm-3.97-3.03a.75.75 0 0 0-1.08.022L7.477 9.417 5.384 7.323a.75.75 0 0 0-1.06 1.06L6.97 11.03a.75.75 0 0 0 1.079-.02l3.992-4.99a.75.75 0 0 0-.01-1.05z"/>

                    </svg>
                    <div>
                        <i className="bi bi-trash"></i>

                        {task.name}
                    </div>
                </div>
                ) :
                (
                <div className="alert alert-danger d-flex align-items-center" role="alert">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" fill="currentColor" className="bi bi-exclamation-triangle-fill flex-shrink-0 me-2" viewBox="0 0 16 16" role="img" aria-label="Warning:">
                    <path d="M8.982 1.566a1.13 1.13 0 0 0-1.96 0L.165 13.233c-.457.778.091 1.767.98 1.767h13.713c.889 0 1.438-.99.98-1.767L8.982 1.566zM8 5c.535 0 .954.462.9.995l-.35 3.507a.552.552 0 0 1-1.1 0L7.1 5.995A.905.905 0 0 1 8 5zm.002 6a1 1 0 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 0 1 0-2z"/>
                    </svg>
                    <div>
                    {task.name}
                    <button style={{marginLeft : '10%'}} onClick={() =>  handleDelete()}>
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" className="bi bi-trash" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path d="M5.5 5.5A.5.5 0 0 1 6 6v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5Zm2.5 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5Zm3 .5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v6a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0V6Z"></path>
                    <path d="M14.5 3a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H13v9a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V4h-.5a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1H6a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1h3.5a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v1ZM4.118 4 4 4.059V13a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h6a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V4.059L11.882 4H4.118ZM2.5 3h11V2h-11v1Z"></path>
                    </svg>
                    </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                )
                }
            </div>

            )
        }
        </div>
    )
}


export default GetTask
```

the second file:

```
import { useEffect,useState } from "react"

const DeleteTask = ({id}) => {
 
        useEffect(() => {
            (async () => {
            try{
                    await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/v1/tasks/${id}`,{
                        method: 'DELETE',
                        headers : {
                            'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
                        }
                    })
            }
            catch(error){
                    console.log(`your delete request was not sucessfully`)
            }
            })()
        },[])
        console.log("completed")
}

export default DeleteTask
```

Comment: Where do I even start, it's so messy, why do you have a `DeleteTask` component that returns no JSX? While wrong, you might pass the `id` to the `useEffect` of your `DeleteTask` component, but you aren't dispatching the received response *success* or *fail*, so how would you know if its deletion succeeded? Why instead don't you just call `fetch` inside your `handleDelete` function? My point here is don't overcomplicate things when you don't have to.

Comment: And in your `onClick={() => handleDelete()}` you aren't passing the `task.id`.

Comment: you need to find a good react learning resource and learn react. this is not how you call a function in react.

Answer (score -1):

You aren't passing the task id in your delete call in your button. Do this instead

```
<button onClick ={(task.id)=>handleDelete(task.id)}> </button>
```

Also, your state does not change as you  run you useEffect hook to grab the values only once. So even if you delete, your tasks state won't change.

Also, you may check your database to ensure the task deleted is actually being deleted. You can put console.log('Deleted successfully') at the end of your delete controllers and even in your react application after you run the fetch() to delete.

You donot need to call the delete fetch call inside another file.

In your handleDelete method, do this:

```
 const async handleDelete = (id) => {

     
      return (async () => {
            try{
                    await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/v1/tasks/${id}`,{
                        method: 'DELETE',
                        headers : {
                            'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
                        }
                    })
            }
            catch(error){
                    console.log(`your delete request was not sucessfully`)
            }
            })()

    }
```

You will need to await it your button component

```
<button onClick ={(task.id)=>await handleDelete(task.id)}> </button>
```

If you have problems regarding async await, try using callback function instead with .then and .catch. Here is a documentation for it
[mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)